# Add a downloaded JS file to WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a very large table (horizontally speaking) on my webpage and I added a scrollbar using the "overflow-y: auto;" property on my CSS, which does what I want.

The problem is that this table is also quite tall (vertically) and I'd like to have a scrollbar both at the top and bottom of it.

I recently downloaded the following JS file: https://github.com/sniku/jQuery-doubleScroll/ to solve that issue. I uploaded it on my child-theme directory under /js/ subfolder.

In my functions.php file, I added the following lines:

```
function dsb_adding_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('doubleScroll', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.doubleScroll.js', array('jquery'),'0.3', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('doubleScroll');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dsb_adding_scripts' );
```

As recommanded in the github page, I also started the table as follows:

```
<div id="double-scroll"><table id="very-wide-element">
```

All of this does not work, in the end.

On the example file, it says that I should use the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#double-scroll').doubleScroll();
    });
</script>
```

However, this is not the proper way to work with WordPress (as seen on the codex) and this is why I did not use it.

Obviously, while switching from using the `<script>` tag onto using the wp_enqueue_scripts function, there is something that I did wrong and I can't find out what.

Sorry if this seems obvious to you but I'm new to JS.

Thank you very much for your help and time.

Comment: You need to enqueue your script then you need to include the example javascript in a javascript file. This should get you working.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be achieved using just CSS. 

For these two elements: set {overflow-x: visible} in your div element's class, and set {overflow-y: visible} in your table's class. (visible shows the scrollbar and sets the overflow to auto also)

CSS:
.div{overflow-x: visible}
.table{overflow-y: visible}

HTML:
(div id="double-scroll" class="div"//table id="very-wide-element" class="table")